# Cisco 4500X TCAM question on PBR

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

I have a pair of 4500x in VSS mode and i have 100-150x SVIs and i have PBR under those SVIs and i am changing their next-hop, i want to know PBR and changing next-hop happens in TCAM, hardware or it is changing the next-hop by CPU?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It’s difficult to know what exactly you’re asking.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no tunneling like GRE and CEF is enabled the PBR is handled by CEF.

If you want to fast switch the PBR you can use `ip route-cache policy` under the interface.

Best